# Using a two column dataframe to have a time counter, but reset on a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have two columns in a dataframe, one called `Total Time`, and one called `cycle`. `Total time` is the time between each instance in the dataframe occuring, and `cycle` indicates what cycle that the time belongs to. I want to create a time column, `Cycle Time`, that shows the acccumulation of total time during each cycle. I have code that almost works, but with one exception - it adds the time on between each cycle, which I don't want (when the cycle changes, I want the counter to completely reset). Here is my current code, to better understand what I'm aiming to achieve:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Cycle": [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5],
                   "Total Time": [0,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.7,1.0,1.0,1.2,1.3,1.3,1.5,1.6,1.6,1.8,1.8]})


df['Cycle Time'] = df['Total Time'].diff().fillna(0).groupby(df['Cycle']).cumsum()


print(df['Cycle Time'])

0     0.0
1     0.2
2     0.2
3     0.2
4     0.2
5     0.5
6     0.5
7     0.3
8     0.3
9     0.5
10    0.1
11    0.1
12    0.3
13    0.1
14    0.1
15    0.3
16    0.3
```

As there is time between each new cycle, the cycle resets so there is no time difference between the first two instances of the new cycle (except in the first cycle). This also occurs at certain stages in the total time, where the time remains the same. Ideally, my output would look like this:

```
0     0.0
1     0.2
2     0.2
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     0.3
6     0.3
7     0.0
8     0.0
9     0.2
10    0.0
11    0.0
12    0.2
13    0.0
14    0.0
15    0.2
16    0.2
```

Basically, I'd like to create a counter that adds up all the time of each cycle, but resets to zero at the first instance of the new cycle in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is:

```
df['Cycle Time'] = (df.groupby('Cycle')['Total Time']
                      .apply(lambda s: s.diff().fillna(0).cumsum())
                    )
```

But this is not so efficient, as you get the diff to then take the cumsum.

What you want is equivalent to just subtracting the initial value per group:

```
df['Cycle Time'] = df['Total Time'].sub(
                    df.groupby('Cycle')['Total Time'].transform('first')
                    )
```

output:

```
    Cycle  Total Time  Cycle Time
0       1         0.0         0.0
1       1         0.2         0.2
2       1         0.3         0.3
3       2         0.4         0.0
4       2         0.4         0.0
5       2         0.7         0.3
6       2         0.9         0.5
7       3         1.0         0.0
8       3         1.0         0.0
9       3         1.2         0.2
10      4         1.3         0.0
11      4         1.3         0.0
12      4         1.5         0.2
13      5         1.6         0.0
14      5         1.6         0.0
15      5         1.8         0.2
16      5         2.1         0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is giving me negative values after the second cycle, counting down to the end of the cycle? I should have also stated that during each cycle, sometimes the time will be the same between steps in the cycle (I'm applying this to a much larger dataset) So your solution isn't working as intended

Comment: Can you please update your example and the expected output to reflect this?

Comment: I have updated the example and expected output.

Comment: I believe my answer is producing the expected output

Comment: Thansk, but my question contains the expected output at the end of it, it is slightly different from your response

Comment: I ran the code on your new example and I'm sorry but I failed to see the difference, can you pinpoint it?

Comment: I apologize! After leaving for a while it I realize I didn't faithfully take your solution over to my larger code. It works perfect! Thank you so much, and thanks for your patience with me!